# Excel - Conditional Formatting: If the cell above is different, change fill color

Tags: excel, excel-2016

So the problem I have is trying to change the fill color using conditional formatting in excel. This is basically what I want to do:

First I have a column, something like this:

```
1
1
1
2
2
3
4
4
4
```

Now I want to use conditional formatting to check if cell `A2=A1`, if it is to have fill color #1, and so on. Once it gets to cell A4 and it checks that `A4=A3`, if it does not match I want it to switch the fill to fill color #2, and it continues to check. Basically every time the cell does not match the value of the cell above, to switch to a different fill color.

I tried using the OFFSET function to check if that value was the same as the cell above, that worked but once I added the function to conditional formatting it went all funky and did not change colors.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with, using  a new color?

Comment: You keep saying colors, how many colors 2-3-4?

Answer (score 0):

Using your sample data, say you put them into cell A1 to A9, **highlight cell A2:A9 only**, and set up the conditional formatting as shown below.

For duplicated value you will use `=A2=A1`

For different value you will use `=A2<>A1`

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

- select a cell outside of your table (let's say it's Z1) and fill it with the value: AB
- cell B1 value: A
- in all cells from B2 downwards: =IF(A2=A1,B1,SUBSTITUTE($Z$1,B1,""))
- it means that if A2<>A1, B2="B"; if A3=A2, B3=B2="B"
- fill all cells on column A with the color you want for "cluster" B: let's say it's blue
- add "$B1="A" in conditional formatting, filling = red